# Android Dependencies annotations.jar crashes project

Tags: android

I have an Android API 10 project which was running fine until I upgraded to Eclipse Kepler from Juno. Now, when I try to run it, I get these errors:

•   [2013-11-27 16:39:42 - RoboSkorz] Dx trouble writing output: already prepared

•   [2013-11-27 16:39:42 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the
    Eclipse log for stack trace.

•   [2013-11-27 16:39:42 - RoboSkorz] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute
    dex:java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.

I did a clean install of the latest Eclipse Kepler, Android SDK and the Eclipse ADT plugin. No help.

Eclipse adds the annotations.jar in Android Dependencies folder. If I remove the jar from the build path, the project builds and runs OK. But, when I exit and re-start Eclipse, it adds the jar back, and the project fails to run again.

Is the annotations.jar needed for API 10? If not, how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem which caused the annotations.jar to crash my program, but I'm not sure exactly which change did the trick.

It seemed like the problem resulted from some version incompatibility between the annotations.jar, and other things in the project. I uninstalled both Eclipse and the Android SDK. I re-installed the SDK in a new folder with no spaces in its name and no previous security restrictions (c:\programs). I ran the Android SDK Manager and added components and APIs I needed. I re-installed Eclipse in the same folder. I installed the Android plugin in Eclipse.

It worked.